# Prestashop 1.5.6.0 override controller never get execute

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I try to use override Category controller

```
<?php

class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();        
    mail('test@gmail.com', 'subject', 'message');
    $this->setTemplate($this->getTpl());
    mail('test@gmail.com', 'subject', 'message2');
  }

  protected function getTpl()
  {
    $layout = _PS_THEME_DIR_ . 'category.tpl';

    if ($parents = $this->category->getParentsCategories(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')))
    {
        foreach ($parents as $parent)
        {
            $parent = (object) $parent;
            if (isset($parent->link_rewrite))
            {
                $categoryLayoutOverride = _PS_THEME_DIR_ . 'layouts/categories/' . $parent->link_rewrite . '/category.tpl';
                if (file_exists($categoryLayoutOverride))
                {
                    $layout = $categoryLayoutOverride;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $layout;
}
}
```

However I never get the mail function to execute. That means this controller never get execute in the first place. How do I solve this problem?

The file name is **CategoryController.php** and put in this folder **override/controllers/front/CategoryController.php**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the override to take effect you have to delete `cache/class_index.php`.

Comment: wow thanks I dont see this near the prestashop override readme